# Most efficient active record query to see if record is a favorite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Quick question.

I have a rails app that has a Book model.

I also have a "favorite" and "rating" model.

Each Book can be favorited by a user and the users can rate the book.

Each time a book is favorited or rated, a new favorite or rating active record entry is created.

So if I am listing all the books in an index view, I want the Book model to have a is_favorited attribue on it to see if the current logged in user favorited it... like this

```
class book




  def favorite
    isFavorite = false
    if User.current_user
      favorite = Favorite.where(:attraction_id => self.id, :user_id => User.current_user.id)
      if favorite.length > 0
        isFavorite = true
      else
        isFavorite = false
      end
    end

    return isFavorite
  end
end
```

I know this is not the most efficient way to do this.

What is the proper way to do something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: As always in code, many ways to skin a cat.  And the most efficient depends on several things including load and number of books, and on and on.   Which database are you using?

Comment: Can a user have multiple favourites, or only one?

Answer (score 0):

Unrelated, but this code:

```
  def favorite
    isFavorite = false
    if User.current_user
      favorite = Favorite.where(:attraction_id => self.id, :user_id => User.current_user.id)
      if favorite.length > 0
        isFavorite = true
      else
        isFavorite = false
      end
    end

    return isFavorite
  end
```

might be better expressed as:

```
  def favorite
    return false unless User.current_user

    favorites = Favorite.where(attraction_id: self.id, user_id: User.current_user.id)
    favorites.length > 0
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

What your code now does is retrieve all favourites from the database, and then return the length of the array. It is much better to just ask the `count` so the query immediately returns *only* the number of favourites.

Also, it would be much cleaner to just hand down the user as a parameter, to decouple your code. So something like this:

```
class book

  def favorited_by(user)
    return false if user.nil?

    Favorite.where(:attraction_id => self.id, :user_id => user.id).count > 0
  end

end
```

Now, how I would prefer to write this, is to use associations, for some reason your foreign key is called `attraction_id`, so assuming this is not a polymorphic association, you could just write:

```
has_many :favorites, foreign_key: :attraction_id
```

and then the code gets even cleaner:

```
favorites.where(user_id: user.id).count > 0
```